# -@ precedes shell script, what does it mean

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, busybox

please see the following code in `busybox` makefile

```
scripts/config/conf: scripts/config/Makefile
     $(MAKE) -C scripts/config conf
     -@if [ ! -f .config ] ; then \
       cp $(CONFIG_DEFCONFIG) .config; \
     fi
```

my question is that what does **-@** before the if clause? it is really frustrating.

thanks in advance!

Comment: i am a newbie in makefile, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Read again GNU [make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/) on [recipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes.html)

The [at sign `@`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Echoing.html) disables echoing.

The [minus sign `-`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html) disables stop on error.

It is a `make` convention (not a shell one).